# mutex and interrupts: How does interrupt behave if mutex is already locked?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, microcontroller, interrupt

i am trying to track and log some data for a program in esp32c3. This data should be accessible by multiple threads(critical data). I am unsure of the behaviour of such a program if it goes into the interrupt handler when the mutex is already locked by other threads. Does the interrupt handler get blocked or what? To be specific, if mutex is locked by thread1/2 and the alarm triggers, what happens in `sig_handler`?

If the `sig_handler` gets blocked, what can i do to resolve this issue? I have to log some data every 1 minute without fail. This sig_handler should be the highest priority when it triggers and it should never be blocked under any circumstances.

```
struct logger
{
 volatile _Atomic uint16_t latency; // in millisecs
 volatile _Atomic uint16_t message_count;
 volatile _Atomic uint16_t alarm_count; //number of times alarm/callback is triggered
 volatile _Atomic clock_t start_time; // start time when sending out GET requests  
}exp_data = {
  .latency = 0,
  .message_count = 0,
  .alarm_count = 0,
  .start_time = 0,
};

static pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void sig_handler(int signum)
{
  if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) ==0)
  {
    //modify exp_data
    //use FILE *fptr to write to some log file
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }
}
void thread1()
{ 
 ...multiple cases of callbacks in this thread1()
 //enter this callback below if receive some signal cond
 if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) ==0)
 {
   exp_data.start_time = clock();
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 }
}

void thread2()
{ 
 ....multiple cases of callbacks in this thread2()
 //enter this callback below if receive some signal cond
 if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) ==0)
 {
   timer_t now_time = clock();
   exp_data.latency = (now_time - exp_data.start_time) * (1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); 
   exp_data.message_count++;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 }
}

void main()
{
//create thread 1 & 2 to run concurrently
//
  if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL)!= 0){
ESP_LOGE(TAG1, "Failed to init mutex!\n");
}
if ( (signal(SIGALRM, sig_handler) ) == SIG_ERR){
ESP_LOGE(TAG1, "Failed to init signal\n");
}
alarm(60); //trigger an ISR every minute
}
```

**EDIT**
I am not using the inbuilt hardware timer library for the mcu because there are some issues that i do not wish to go into as i would have to spend too much time. i simply want to write a simple timer/alarm program to get the job done so i am using C's own alarm and timer lib

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock()` is not signal-safe. You'll get deadlock. I don't know if your platform support `signalfd()`, if yes, you can use it and handle signals in dedicated thread. By the way, stdio functions aren't signal-safe too.

Comment: As alternative you can block signal and wait for it in a thread with `sigwait()`

Comment: @dimich do you mean when the signal triggers i will block it across all threads/processes and catch it with a separate thread specially to handle that signal only?

Comment: No, block signal once at the beginning to avoid default handler invocation. Then wait for signal with sigwait() in a thead with mutex unlocked. After signal unblocks sigwait(), lock mutex, modify your data, unlock mutex and wait for signal again. UPD: yes, you'll need separate thread for signal handling.